# Como ver la diferencia entre horas, minutos y segundos en dos fechas en Mysql

Tags: mysql-workbench

Como puedo calcular las diferencias de horas,minutos y segundos en dos fechas en Mysql.

Hasta el momento solo tengo calculado la hora con un  alias Horas, pero también quiero calcular los minutos y segundos con sus alias.

```
select timestampdiff(HOUR,'2020-05-11 17:33:00' ,'2020-05-12 18:47:21') as Horas from  altavehiculos where idVehiculo = 1;
```